# How can I automatize reading and writing files?

Tags: python

I would like to read a lot of data in a folder, and want to delete lines that have `"DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE)"`, and then write it as new data. 
In that Data folder, there are 300 data files!

My code is

```
import os, sys
path = "/Users/xxx/Data/"

allFiles = os.listdir(path)

for fname in allFiles:
    print(fname)

    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        with open(fname, "w") as w:
            for line in f:
                if "DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE)" not in line:
                    w.write(line)
```

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1147.dat'
> ```

I want to do it for a bunch of dataset.
How can I automatically read and write to delete the lines?
and is there way to make a new dataset with a different name? e.g. `1147.dat -> 1147_new.dat`

Comment: You might need to read all the contents of the file, before doing `open(x, 'w')` because write mode will wipe the file. so, `data = f.read(); for line in data: ...`.

Comment: You just want to delete the line that contains `"DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE)"` and leave everything else the same, correct?

Comment: @Torxed Not working..
The error message is coming from with open(fname,"r") as f:
not just with open(fname,'w') as w:

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Correct, but I have hundreds of files that has same data format, but different values.
How can I handle that much data files?

with open("1174.dat", "r") as f:
    with open("1174_new.dat", "w") as w:
        for line in f:
            if "DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE)" not in line:
                w.write(line)

This code was working for a data file though..

Comment: Yea you need the full path, since you're not standing in `/Users/xxx/Data/` you need to do `with open(path + fname, 'r')`. The error message is quite self explanatory.

Comment: `listdir` gives only filename without path so you have to join `path` with `fname` to have correct path to file - ie. `fullpath = os.path.join(path, fname)`

Comment: @furas That helped! I think os.path.join is good to use!

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Fair point, I suggest you use the "Flag" feature to gain attention from moderators with the ability to oppose / re-open questions you feel aren't properly marked as duplicate. I don't dare to re-open based on your comment with the risk of getting backlash from re-opening something that shouldn't. The main problem here is that it's a XY problem, the solution is sort of there - and instead of asking why the error occurs OP asks how to do the whole thing. So me personally still think this is a duplicate. And your answer below is still valid and good as it stands :)

Comment: @Torxed Didn't know flags can be used to this end - thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do; code demos of what each annotated line does afterwards:

```
path = "/Users/xxx/Data/"
allFiles = [os.path.join(path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(path)] # [1]
del_keystring = "DT=(SINGLE SINGLE SINGLE)" # general case

for filepath in allFiles: # better longer var names for clarity
    print(filepath)

    with open(filepath,'r') as f_read: # [2]
        loaded_txt = f_read.readlines()
    new_txt = []
    for line in loaded_txt:
        if del_keystring not in line:
            new_txt.append(line)
    with open(filepath,'w') as f_write: # [2]
        f_write.write(''.join([line for line in new_txt])) # [4]

    with open(filepath,'r') as f_read: # [5]
        assert(len(f_read.readlines()) <= len(loaded_txt))
```

- **[1](http://gist.github.com/Torxed/8d12d9cd0f543b81140df8cf348cfa6f)** `os.listdir` returns only the *filenames*, not the filepaths; `os.path.join` joins its inputs into a fullpath, with separators (e.g. `\\`): `folderpath + '\\' + filename`
- **[2]** NOT same as doing `with open(X,'r') as .., with open(X,'w') as ..:`; the `as 'w'` *empties the file*, thus nothing for `as 'r'` to read
- **[3]** If `f_read.read() == "Abc\nDe\n12"`, then `f_read.read().split('\n')==["Abc,"De","12"]`
- **[4]** Undoes [3]: if `_ls==["a","bc","12"]`, then `"\n".join([x for x in _ls])=="a\nbc\n12"`
- **[5]** Optional code to verify that saved file's # of lines is `<=` original file's
- **NOTE**: you may see the saved filesize slightly *bigger* than original's, which may be due to original's better packing, compression, etc - which you can figure from its docs; [5] ensures it isn't due to more lines

---

```py
# bonus code to explicitly verify intended lines were deleted
with open(original_file_path,'r') as txt:
    print(''.join(txt.readlines()[:80])) # select small excerpt
with open(processed_file_path,'r') as txt:
    print(''.join(txt.readlines()[:80])) # select small excerpt
# ''.join() since .readlines() returns a list, delimited by \n
```

---

**NOTE**: for more advanced caveats, see comments below answer; for a more compact alternative, see [Torxed's version](http://gist.github.com/Torxed/8d12d9cd0f543b81140df8cf348cfa6f)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199937/discussion-on-answer-by-overlordgolddragon-how-can-i-automatize-reading-and-writ).